# is it right to say 'Let's saunter after dinner' or 'Let's go for a walk after dinner' or other?

Tags: american-english

If after having a dinner with friends then I hope to walk outside with them.
how can i say?

is it right to say 'Let's saunter after dinner' or 'Let's go for a walk after dinner' or other ?

Comment: Native speakers would understand, but might think it strange, and assume you were a non-native-speaker who had seen 'saunter' in a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making the suggestion after dinner, **Let's go for a walk** is all you need.

Other ways of saying the same thing are: **Shall we go for a walk?** / **Do you fancy a walk?** / **Do you feel like a walk?**

If you have are making the suggestion either before or during dinner, you might say: **Let's go for a walk after dinner.**

Note Michael Harvey's comment above.

Comment: To saunter is to walk in a slow, relaxed fashion, often with no particular destination in mind. It is a style or manner of walking. When suggesting a walk, we don't often specify the manner in which the walking is to be done.